# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (CPANEL)

Tags: node.js, cors, cpanel

I am working on project (angular && nodejs) that works perfect on "Developing Mode".
When I upload the project to CPANEL (LIVE SITE) everything works when I am fetch data from my database.
When I am trying to fetch data from "outsource Api" I am gettin an error messages (picture of error https://i.stack.imgur.com/io3JB.png):

I tried to make those requests that make the problems from the angular directly (without use NODEJS) than everything works perfect. But this is not secure solution.

Maybe the glitch happens because the API service is free and as soon as the API server "feels" that I'm making the call from a live site, he doesn't cooperate ???
(its coinGecko) (https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation).

THIS IS MY APP.JS:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
// require('./sqlConnect');
const signup = require('./services/signup');
const login = require('./services/login');
const crypto = require('./services/crypto');
const portfolio = require('./services/portfolio');
const googleSignUp = require('./services/googleSignUp');
const session = require('express-session');


const app = express();

// const unGuards = [
//     '/login',
//     '/logout',
//     '/signup',
// ];

app.use(session({
    secret: 'my-secret',
    name: 'mySession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
}));

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello Worldi");
});

app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        params: req.params,
        query: req.query,
    });
});


function authGurd(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
}

app.get('/crypto', authGurd, crypto.getCrypto); 
app.put('/crypto/:id/:coinsAmount', authGurd, crypto.getCoin); 
app.get('/cryptos/:userName', authGurd, crypto.getCryptos); 
app.get('/removeCoin/:tableNameToRemove/:idToRemove', authGurd, crypto.removeCoin); 
app.get('/cryptosPicture/:coinName', authGurd, crypto.cryptosPicture); 
app.get('/createTable/:userName', authGurd, crypto.createTable); 

app.post('/googleSignUp', googleSignUp.GoogleSignUp);
app.post('/googleSignUp', googleSignUp.googleLogIn);

app.get('/login', login.getLoginStatus);
app.get('/logout', login.logout);
app.post('/signup', signup.signup);
app.post('/login', login.login);
```

PLEASE TELL ME IF YOU SEE A PROBLEM :(

THIS IS MY REQUEST (NODEJS) (ITS WORKS ON DEVELOPING MODE BUT NOT ON THE LIVE SITE):

```
exports.showMeThePicture = function (req, res) {

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search?query=${req.body[0]}`,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  };
  
  axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    res.send(response.data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Picture of the Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/io3JB.png

THANK YOU A LOT !!!

Comment: Error 502 means bad gateway. Ie seems your cpanel isn't configured correctly and the request may not even be able to reach your server ... Maybe some port configuration is wrong? I never used cpanel myself, so I can't help you with that. But your node code seems about right on the first glimpse ...

Comment: Never ever use `origin: true` with `credentials: true` in your CORS configuration. It's just too insecure...